# Листаемый список без кода Java (Android)

Tags: android, listview, java

Добрый день, скажите, пожалйста, можно ли создать листаемый ListView без кода Java, как здесь:

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/lv"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <Button ... />
  <ImageButton ... />
<TextView ... />
</ListView>
```

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь за большое кол-во ошиьок, така как пишу с планшета

Comment: Гм. Не совсем понял, чего вы хотите. Задать статичные элементы `ListView` непосредственно в файле layout'а?

Comment: Не совсем статичные. Там будет несколько кнопок, текст на которых будет меняться. Ещё что-то слышал о ScrollView, подойдёт ли он?

Comment: Если нужна просто скроллируемая область — да, `ScrollView`/`HorizontalScrollView` вполне подойдут.

Comment: Да это то, что мне нужно. Спасибо. Ваш ответ на всякий случай отметил как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать в качестве элементов `ListView` массив строк — `android:entries`. Если же хотите свою разметку элементов — только через адаптер.